# Two's complement on an unsigned integer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How can I implement a two's complement in VB.NET using unsigned integer types such as Byte, UShort, UInteger and ULong?  Can I cast a UInteger to an Integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't cast. That will result in an overflow exception for large values.
You can, however, do this:

```
intValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(uintValue), 0)
```

But what stops you from doing the math with the unsigned values without casting them to something? It just works.

Comment: Performance.  I just wondered if there was a way.  You can cast in C++ without converting to a different representation.  4294967295 - (x - 1) works too.

Comment: @jnm2 Is there a performance problem with `Dim b As UInteger = Not a`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) can proabably explain it better than I can in the space I have here, but `Not` is not a two's complement operator.  Not 0 = 4294967295, but -0 = 0.  Not 1 = 4294967294, but -1 = 4294967295.

Comment: (Not x) + 1 works too.  Never mind.  But you have to check for x = 0 first.